# Change scroll bar of menu list only

Tags: css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,70); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(239,149,36,100); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,30); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,30); 
}
```

I found this css online which modified the style of the scroll bar. However it also changed the scroll bar of the page itself and I need it to change only the one of the menu list. The menu list id is "cssmenu" . Is it possible and how please?

Comment: Have you tried putting `#cssmenu` in front of those selectors? Like `#cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Just use any selector before your scroll rules

```css
.myscroll {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.myscroll p {
  height: 2000px;
}

.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
/* Track */
.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,70); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(239,149,36,100); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,30); 
}
.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,30); 
}
```

```html
<div class="myscroll">
  <p>Content<p>
</div>
```

Comment: .cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
/* Track */
.cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,70); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
.cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(239,149,36,100); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,30); 
}
.cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,30); 
}

Still not working this way